# Can a t-test be used to compare means obtained from samples of the same batch but tested in two different labs?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, independence

I have two datasets containing size measurements. The initial dataset originates from six different aliquots drawn from a large batch of a product (a suspension with particles). Each sample was individually transferred to its own vial and subsequently measured three times (yielding three replicates per aliquot). The mean was computed from these three replicates, resulting in a total of six means generated by lab A.

The second dataset originates from another sampling event performed a month later, again consisting of six separate aliquots drawn from the same batch. These samples were similarly transferred to six vials and measured three times, resulting in six means obtained by lab B, utilizing a similar device, precisely the same model and methodology.
My aim is to investigate whether there exists a significant difference between the means of both samples. I'm intending to use a t-test to verify whether the two devices yield similar results, using the 6 determination results of lab A vs the 6 determination results of lab B.

However, I am not sure about which t-test (independent or dependent) to use.
Previously, paired measurements were performed on 3 different batches of a different product by Lab A and Lab B. Lab A had results for batch A, batch B, and batch C; similarly, Lab B had results for the same batches. To demonstrate that there was no significant difference, a paired t-test was performed. The dataset I want to test also comprises results from a batch that were measured in Lab A and Lab B. There is nothing unusual or complicated in obtaining the aliquots. My concern is that there might still be dependency, considering that the historical test was also based on dependency?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you explain how "six separate aliquots" from a batch and another six separate aliquots might fail to be independent?  Ordinarily, random selection of aliquots will *guarantee* independence, suggesting something unusual and complicated happens in obtaining the aliquots.  That would help us understand what your concern might be.

Comment: Hi whuber, I updated my question in the field above. I hope this helps, thanks again.